# Solubility of carbon dioxide in 1M sodium hydroxide solution?

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility

I know that carbon dioxide is soluble and forms carbonic acid, but exactly how is solubility measured?

How soluble is carbon dioxide in a 1M solution of sodium hydroxide?

Comment: Difficult question, because there is the physical solubility of the gas itself which is in equilibrium with all the carbonate species.

Comment: The question is really somewhat out of whack. In sodium hydroxide any  carbon dioxide is converted to the carbonate anion. In a strong sodium +1 solution sodium carbonate has limited solubility, and will ppt out. So until the NaOH is substantially reacted there really isn't any "dissolved" carbon dioxide.

Comment: If you are still interested in this, do you mean the analytical methodology for quantifying carbon dioxide or the experimental procedure before the carbon dioxide analysis part?

Comment: This is a useful recent article for measuring solubility: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/je200991x. Note that fundamentally solubility is a physical equilibrium but in many instances, it involves chemical reactions.